# Applications of Several Complex Variables.

Tags: applications, several-complex-variables

I am kinda curious about SCV because I saw (somewhere on Math Stackexchange) about all the math involved and I was thinking...what kinds of applications do SCV find in the natural sciences and maths?(Or even Computer Science). I did a little research but I didn't really find much.